# npm csv-parser: skip header line, return array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am working with the [csv-parse module in npm](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/) to download a CSV file over Ajax. I want to read it into an array of objects.

Here is the CSV file that I'm working with:

```
val,row_id,date,row_name
19378.02,10Q,2013-10-01,NHS Oxfordshire
14104.81,01M,2014-01-01,NHS North Manchester
11130.65,09D,2014-09-01,NHS Brighton & Hove
3611.32,08J,2014-11-01,NHS Kingston
```

And here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: _this.globalOptions.numeratorUrl,
      error: function() {
       // show error
      },
      success: function(data) {
        parse(data,
             {columns: ['val','row_id','date','row_name'] },
             function(err, output){
                console.log('parsed', output);
             }
        );
      }
```

This works, but there are two things I would like to improve:

- By default it includes the header row, so `output[0]` looks like this: `{ 'val': 'val', 'row_id': 'row_id', ...}`. Is there some way I can automatically skip the header row?
- I don't like the fact that I have to define `columns` explicitly in order to produce an array of objects. The name and the ordering of the columns may vary. Is there some way I can automatically use the values from the header row, whatever they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the documentation, by link given:

columns (array|boolean|function) List of fields as an array, a user defined callback accepting the first line and returning the column names or `true if autodiscovered in the first CSV line`, default to null, affect the result data set in the sense that records will be objects instead of arrays.

and that is an answer, so

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: _this.globalOptions.numeratorUrl,
  error: function() {
   // show error
  },
  success: function(data) {
    parse(data,
         {columns: true },
         function(err, output){
            console.log('parsed', output);
         }
    );
  }
```

Comment: That works! Thank you, I just found the phrasing of the documentation confusing.

Comment: If you use custom column names, use option `fromLine: 2` to skip first line.